# When a government decide to 'do' a referendum, what's the word/verb for it?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a government decides to 'do' a referendum, what's the word/verb for it? Run, establish, form... etc?

Here is the sentence I need it for:

"The Catalan government disobeyed the Spanish constitution when they ______ a referendum in hope that Catalonia could become independent of Spain."

Answer (score 7):

A [referendum](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/referendum) is *called* (when it is first proposed) and then *held* (when the actual vote takes place).

According to [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=held%20a%20referendum%2Ccalled%20a%20referendum%2Chold%20a%20referendum%2Ccall%20a%20referendum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheld%20a%20referendum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalled%20a%20referendum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chold%20a%20referendum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccall%20a%20referendum%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Here's a [quote from ABC News Australia](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-10-06/spains-top-court-halts-catalan-secession-parliament-meeting/9021350) concerning the [2017 Catalan independence referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_independence_referendum,_2017):

> Catalan leaders held an independence referendum on Sunday that was
>   banned by Madrid and marked by violent scenes at electoral stations
>   where Spanish police sought to hinder voting.

Comment: This answer is essentially correct, but it could be better.  You might want to try to differentiate between _calling_ and _holding_ a referendum, since the former refers to initiating the process and the latter to actually executing it.

Comment: @AikenDrum A quote from the news referring to the Catalan referendum would also be useful.